# Calculate file size manually (ASCII values)

Tags: c

I need to make a work to college (Simple tasks) and one of the questions is:

> Calculate the file size containing the following code:

```
main ()
{
   int x;
   soma (x);
}
```

Calculating manually I find the size to be 34 bytes.

Using the unix shell command `$ stat -c %s prog.c` I get 35 bytes.

Each line counts as 2 bytes and a tab 1, doesn't match...

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Open the file with a hex editor and see what's really there..

Comment: @Hunter McMillen i created this file and i need to know in bytes it's size, manually it gives me 34 bytes, when i use the shell command it gives me 35 bytes

Comment: @Souza There is an "end of line" character after the last line, so it should be 35.

Comment: What do you mean by "calculating manually" - how are you doing that exactly?

Comment: I am guessing the project is actually to `read()` the file and count its bytes without using `filesize()` or whatever API.  Otherwise this looks like more of a 'Mechanical Turk' problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get 35 bytes from what you pasted.  I also see no tabs there; 4 spaces is not a tab.  (Most Unix utilities use 8-space tabs.)  That said, you need to use something like `cat -v`, `:set list` in `vi`, hex editor, etc. to see what's really in the file.  (Consider trailing spaces, for one example.)

Comment: GREAT! Sorry, didn't realized it was not a tab there!!
Need to wait 8 minutes to accept your answer